# Changing from the standard directory Bitcoin-Qt/Bitcoin-Core uses, to a remote disk (MacOSX)

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-qt-setup

I'm currently downloading the Blockchain on Bitcoin-Qt and i'd like to change from the standard directory Bitcoin-Qt stores the data (on mac) =

> ~/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/

to a harddrive, but can you do this without re-installing bitcoin core and choosing a different directory? If not, can you just drag and drop the data you've already downloaded/synced in to the new directory so that bitcoin core identifies that as the real blockchain, and that you don't have to re-download/re-sync everything?

It does not answer my question, i want to know how to change directory of the blockchain data on a Mac, not on Windows.

Comment: If by "remote disk" you mean a network drive of some kind, I would recommend against this.  You can get it to work with symbolic links in your operating system, but I've found that it becomes very slow.  You are essentially turning disk operations into network operations.  If you need to use a different hard drive, I recommend a USB hard drive.

Comment: @Jestin This is for Mac, not for Windows...

Comment: The datadir option is platform independent.  It works the same way on OS X or Linux as it did on Windows.